# Is there a way, using templates, to prevent a class from being derivable in C++

Tags: c++, boost

I need to prevent a class from being derived from so I thought to myself, this is something that Boost is bound to have already done. I know they have a noncopyable, they must have a nonderivable...

Imagine my surprise when I couldn't find it....

That got me thinking.. There must be a reason. Maybe it isn't possible to do using templates..

I'm sure if it was easy it's be in the boost libraries.

I know how to do it without using templates, i.e. using a base class with a private constructor i.e.

```
class ThatCantBeDerived;  // Forward reference

class _NonDeriv
{
    _NonDeriv() {}
    friend class ThatCantBeDerived;
};

class ThatCantBeDerived : virtual public _NonDeriv
{
public:
    ThatCantBeDerived() :
      _NonDeriv()
    {
    }
};
```

Or something like this..

Maybe it's the forward reference that causes the problem, or maybe there isn't a portable way to achieve it..

Either way, I'm not sure why it isn't in boost..

Any ideas?

Comment: ScaryA, out of idle curiocity, could you please disclose why one would want to have a non-derivable class? (honest question - I never had a design that would have called for such, but i assume your question has some practical source).

Comment: Identifiers that start with underscore followed by a capital letter (as identifiers that start with double underscore) are reserved for the implementation (compiler + library). You should not call your template `_NonDeriv`.

Comment: @DVK Suppose you are designing a tool that is using a fixed structure that the class maps to directly (i.e. a struct sk_buff) and all of your library makes optimizations/assumptions about that mapping. You surely dont want someone to be able change that do you?

Comment: Why does it have to be templates, why not use private ctor and static construction functions?

Comment: To DVK. Yes, I don't mind telling you why. There is a bug in the Solaris SunPRO C compiler where you cannot delete through a const base pointer if the destructor is virtual.. So for example
struct Bar
{
    virtual ~Bar(){}
};

int main()
{
 
 Bar* p1 = new Bar;
 delete p1;
 
 Bar* p2 = new Bar;
 p2->~Bar();

 const Bar* p3 = new Bar;
 delete p3;
 
 const Bar* p4 = new Bar;
 p4->~Bar();   // line 19: Error: Non-const function Bar::__SLIP.DELETER__A() called for const  customer .
 
 return 0;
}
Will not compile.

Comment: For this reason I want to prevent derivations from a particular class so this bug doesn't manifest itself. I'll make sure my class has a non virtual destructor.

Comment: @ScaryAardvark - Thanks! I need to parse this a beet deeper but I think I understand your logic. Pretty useful approach to know! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the current spec, it is explicitly forbidden to "friend" a template argument, so templatizing your example would make it not standards compliant. Boost probably would not want to add something like that to its libraries. I believe this restriction is being relaxed in Ox however, and there are workarounds for compilers.

Comment: To be fair, the vptr tax mentioned in the c++ faq lite is probably also a very good reason

Answer (score 7):

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.11

Answer (score 3):

There is no way in C++ of preventing derivation - you cannot prevent this situation:

```
class A {};

class B : public A {};
```

However, there are several ways of preventing **instantiation** of objects of type B. Whether this is worth the trouble is debatable. I would prefer to document that the class A is not intended for derivation, and give it a non-virtual destructor.

Also, note that the name **_NonDeriv** is reserved in C++ for the implementation, as are all names that begin with an underscore and an uppercase letter. You are not allowed to create such names in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe has a not-perfect solution for this using templates.

The problem there is that since templates cannot declare argument-dependent friends [*] it relies on the constructor being protected instead of private. It is a partial solution in that it will trigger a compiler error when someone mistakenly decides to derive from your class, but it is not a complete solution since someone intentionally can force the inheritance.

```
template <typename SealedClass>
class seal
{
protected:
   seal() {}
};

class Sealed : private virtual seal<Sealed>
{
//...
};

class NaiveExtension : public Sealed { // fails
   NaiveExtension() {} // NaiveExtension cannot call seal<Sealed> constructor
};

class BreakingExtension : public Sealed, private virtual seal<Sealed> {
   BreakingExtension() : seal<Sealed>(), Sealed() {} // now it can
};
```

The advantage is that it can be templated (the adobe library actually defines a macro that will hide the 'private virtual' from the casual reader). The disadvantage is that it can be broken.

Then again, you can always do what C++FAQ suggests for some questions on blocking some functionalities:

> 'how can I inhibit people from...': *write a comment not to do it*
>
> 'but how do I really inhibit others from...': *write a comment: You will be fired if...*
>
> 'but how do I actually block it in case they don't follow the comment?': *fire them*

[*] This restriction will be taken away with the upcoming standard, whenever available, whenever implemented in compilers...

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

Make all the constructors private:
Then nobdy can derivce from you. Of course this adds othe problems like you can not instanciate a variable of the object, but there are workarounds for that using public static member methods and friends:

```
#include <memory>
class InstnaceCantDeriveFromMe;
class CantDeriveFromMe
{
    private:
        friend class InstnaceCantDeriveFromMe;
        CantDeriveFromMe()
        {}

    public:
        static std::auto_ptr<CantDeriveFromMe>  getDynamicObj()
        {
            return std::auto_ptr<CantDeriveFromMe>(new CantDeriveFromMe());
        }
};

class Plop: public CantDeriveFromMe
{
};

class InstnaceCantDeriveFromMe
{
    private:
        CantDeriveFromMe  instnace;
    public:
        CantDeriveFromMe& get() {return instnace;}
};

int main()
{
    std::auto_ptr<CantDeriveFromMe>  a =     CantDeriveFromMe::getDynamicObj();
    InstnaceCantDeriveFromMe         b;


    // This fails to compile:
    Plop                             c; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe turn your example into a template, using CRTP - the curiously recurring template pattern:

```
template <typename T>
_NonDeriv
{
   _NonDeriv() {}
   friend class T;
};

class ThatCantBeDerived : virtual public _NonDeriv<ThatCantBeDerived>
{
public:
    ThatCantBeDerived() :
      _NonDeriv()
    {
    }
};
```

Might work...

Comment: Ah, Todd Gardner's answer suggests this won't work (until C++0x maybe).

Oh well.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I'd have done. The only reason I stopped was when I thought that this must have been done already in boost...Until I found it wasn't...

Comment: And then @Todd Gardner kindly explained why :)

Comment: Yeah, as I was typing, I was wondering why I've never seen friend used like that in a template...

Comment: Just FYI, a little indirection normally gets around it:

template <typename T> struct Identity { typedef T type; }
template <typename T> class Final { friend class Identity<T>::type; Final() {} }

Comment: @Todd Gardner: I have read and reread the standard, but it is not easy in that part. The standard says that if the *elaborated type specifier resolves to a* typedef-name *or a template* type-parameter *the elaborated-type-specifier is ill formed*. I could not find a precise definition of what *typedef-name* is, it cannot surely be *any* typedef, as that would block most metaprogramming techniques... Anyway I tested the code and g++ does allow it, while comeau compiler complains *error: typedef "type" may not be used in an elaborated type specifier*. It might be non-standard.

Comment: Just tested with intel's compiler and it won't allow it either, I don't have a VS at hand for testing purposes